# MATLAB Creating Tasks while Passing in Matrix Arguments

Tags: matlab, matrix, parallel-processing, task, cells

I'm trying to parallelize a job in Matlab. I have a large set of matrices that I would like to pass to a function, which then returns a vector. What I would like to do is to assign a subset of the matrices to each task and then return their outputs. I have been able to get the code working where each task is assigned only 1 matrix to pass, but when I try to assign multiple matrices to each task, I'm getting the Too Many Arguments error.

From reading the documentation, on [createTask](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/createtask.html), I suspect that the structure that I'm using to pass in the matrices is the problem.

```
numTasks=4;

%Setting up the splitting of my 60 matrices among 4 tasks.
[xSplit, numTasks] =pctdemo_helper_split_vector(linspace(1,60,60, numTasks));

%XSplit shows the splits of the numbers 1-60 to each of 4 cells in XSplit
celldisp(xSplit);

%Substituting in my matrices for the indices in XSplit
for i=1:numTasks

    xSplitVec=xSplit{i};
    for j=1:length(xSplitVec);

        %SCov is an array where I have collected all my matrices
        xSplitMat{i,j}=SCov_array(:,:, xSplitVec(j));

    end
end

parallel.defaultClusterProfile('local');
c = parcluster();

job=createJob(c);
for i=1:numTasks

    xThis=xSplitMat(i,:);

    %@Norm1MinVar_par is my function, which takes matrices and returns a vector
    createTask(job, @Norm1MinVar_par, 1, xThis);

end

submit(job);
wait(job);
y=fetchOutputs(job);
delete(job);
cat(2, y{:})
```

My code follows the example from [Dividing Tasks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/examples/dividing-matlab-computations-into-tasks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
createTask(job, @Norm1MinVar_par, 1, {xThis})
```

`createTask` interprets each element in the cell array of input arguments as a seperate argument to the function, by wrapping it in a cell as I suggest you are telling `createTask` to just provide one input, which itself is a cell. I'm assuming that's what you want of course, I'm guessing as I can't see your definition of `Norm1MinVar_par`.